# Cannot import project created in windows eclipse to mountain lion eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, osx-mountain-lion

I try to import android project backed up from eclipse set up on windows 7 to mac mountain lion elipse but the project is disable as when the project already exist in the project explorer. However i have never imported this project before.

I used file then import then follow the usual project import method.

Someone run in the same issue ? Please help its a weird disadvantage as i have more than 7 projects to import.

Comment: maybe you have a project with the same name in your workspace?

Comment: i have'nt import any project in my workspace with the same project name, i checked it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to Crate another Workspace
2. Try to import your project folder by following this :

   File>> New >> Project >> Android >> Android Project From Existing Code